# Returning the average amount of a column

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table which represents the scores and id's of users who have played a flash game. I want to return the amount of times the average user has tried the game- every time they complete a "try" the score and id of the user is input into the mysql table. The structure is -

```
id int(11)                      
score int(11)                               
fb_id int(25)
```

This gives me the amount of tries for every user

```
SELECT count(score) AS counted FROM `ifa_scores` GROUP BY `fb_id`
```

but i want something like this

i would like the average amount of times played overall- ie the average amount of rows with the same FB_ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to get a count of how many games have been played, and a count of the number of players, join them together, and divide appropriately; something like

```
SELECT GAMES_PLAYED,
       PLAYERS,
       GAMES_PLAYED / PLAYERS AS AVERAGE_GAMES_PER_PLAYER
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS GAMES_PLAYED FROM 'ifa_scores') g,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) AS PLAYERS FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 'fb_id' FROM 'ifa_scores')) p;
```

should work.  Alternatively you could use

```
SELECT AVG(GAMES_PLAYED) AS AVERAGE_GAMES_PER_PLAYER
FROM (SELECT FB_ID, COUNT(*) AS GAMES_PLAYED
        FROM 'ifa_scores'
        GROUP BY 'fb_id');
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT AVG(t.counted)
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(id) AS counted
    FROM ifa_scores
    GROUP BY fb_id
) AS t
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `fb_id`, avg(score) AS counted FROM `ifa_scores` GROUP BY `fb_id`
```

Comment: i would like the average amount of times played overall- ie the average amount of rows with the same FB_ID

Comment: @Chris, that's what the GROUP BY clause does. (It might be an idea to add ``fb_id`` into the SELECT clause, so that you can see which average corresponds to which ``fb_id``.)

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:
count(*) returns number of games played by each user. taking avg of this should give you the answer you are looking for. please check

SELECT fb_id, avg(count(*)) AS counted FROM `ifa_scores` GROUP BY `fb_id`